# Group array by keys value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have searched around and I am at my wits end so I will make this easy.  This is what I have in a print_r:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => client interaction
            [y] => 2.7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => client interaction
            [y] => 0.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => project planning
            [y] => 0.1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => client interaction
            [y] => 5.9
        )

)
```

And this is what I want it to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => client interaction
            [y] => 8.7
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => project planning
            [y] => 0.1
        )

)
```

Comment: There isn't an "easy way". Just iterate over the original array, and build another array of indexed by name.

Answer (score 4):

Is it absolutely necessary that your desired array use numeric indeces? If I were to do this I would do it this way (not the same as your desired array though)

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $item)
{
  if(!isset($newArray[$item["name"]]))
    $newArray[$item["name"]] = 0;

  $newArray[$item["name"]] += $item["y"];
}
```

This will give you an array of this structure:

```
Array
(
  [client interaction] => 8.7
  [project planning] => 0.1
)
```

To get the keys back you simply use the second form of the `foreach` loop

```
foreach($newArray as $name => $y)
```

`$name` will contain the `name` and `$y` the `y` in your original array.

Answer (score 2):

```
$hash = array();
foreach ($sourceArray as $key=>$value) {
   $y = 0;
   if (isset($hash{$value{'name'}})) {
      $y = $hash{$value{'name'}};
   }

   $hash{$value{'name'}} = $y + $value{'y'};
}

$result = array();
foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
  $result[] = array( 'name' => $key, 'value' => $value );
}
print_r($result);
```

The last loop is just to get `$hash` into the exact format you specified.

---

Explanation:

```
$hash
```

Is a temporary structure used to compute the sums for each unique name.

```
foreach ($sourceArray as $key=>$value) {
```

This goes through your original array ($sourceArray) and pulls out each element.

```
   $y = 0;
```

Initializes a variable to store the current sum that belongs with that name.

```
   if (isset($hash{$value{'name'}})) {
```

Checks to see if a value has already been stored in `$hash` for the given name.

```
      $y = $hash{$value{'name'}};
   }
```

Sets $y to the previously calculated sum for the given name, if there was one.

```
   $hash{$value{'name'}} = $y + $value{'y'};
}
```

Stores the sum for the given name into our temporary structure `$hash`.

```
 $result = array();
    foreach ($hash as $key => $value) {
      $result[] = array( 'name' => $key, 'value' => $value );
    }
```

converts $hash to the format you desired.

The empy []'s in `$result[] = ...` add the right hand side of the expression to the end of the `$result` array.

Comment: Hi. Doesn't it look that the operands in this line is inverted? `$y = $hash{$value{'name'}};` I think you meant `$hash{$value{'name'}} = $y;`

Comment: nope, it is correct.  That line is initializing y to what was seen before for the addition on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mixed = array(); // Should contain your array shown above
$groups = array();
$newArray = array(); // Will contain your new array
$counter = 0;

foreach( $mixed as $mix )
{
    if ( isset($groups[$mix['name']]) )
    {
        $newArray[$groups[$mix['name']]]['y'] += $mix['y'];
    }
    else
    {
        $groups[$mix['name']] = $counter;
        $newArray[] = $mix;
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

http://codepad.org/EjdHxgvt